# Referencing Url of Current Web in Sharepoint for timer Jobs

Tags: sharepoint, timer-jobs

Which is the best way to reference current site/web in sharepoint specially for Timer Jobs from the examples given below and why?

Example1:
SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
SPWeb oWeb = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb;

OR

Example2:
using(SPSite site=new SPSite(SPCOntext.Current.Web.Url)){
   using(SPWeb web=site.OpenWeb()){

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You will not get SPContext object in Timer Job. So you have to use the first option.
Or if you know the name you can pass it like
this.webapplication.sites [site name]

Or you can read from the config file of timer job.